# how to limit number of drag and drops

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

1. How to retrieve id of drop target (button by which ChoiceDragListener() class is called)
2. How can I specify drag and drop limit ,i.e. how many times "drag and drop" can be done

This is my code

> design activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:background="@drawable/g"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

  <TableLayout 
     android:id="@+id/table"
     android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TableRow >
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b1"          
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:textSize="26sp" 

              android:text="a"/>
         <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b2"          
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:textSize="26sp" 

              android:text="b"/>


        </TableRow>
         <TableRow >
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b3"          
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:textSize="26sp" 
              android:text="1"/>
          <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b4"          
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:textSize="26sp" 

              android:text="2"/>

        </TableRow> <TableRow >
          <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b5"          
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:textSize="26sp" 

              android:text="A"/>
          <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b6"          
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:textSize="26sp" 

              android:text="B"/>

        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
          package com.example.in;

                  import android.os.Build;

                 import android.os.Bundle;

            import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

          import android.annotation.TargetApi;
        import android.app.Activity;
          import android.content.ClipData;
           import android.graphics.Color;
      import android.graphics.Typeface;
       import android.view.DragEvent;
         import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MotionEvent;
         import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
        import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
       import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final String BTN_TAG ="BUTTON";
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



     Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    Button b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);

    Button b3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);

    Button b4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);

    Button b5=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);

    Button b6=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);


    //b1.setTag(BTN_TAG);


    b1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    b2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    b3.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());


    b4.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    b5.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    b6.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());

}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} 

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:


            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:    

            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:


            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

            Button dropTarget = (Button) v;

            Button dropped = (Button) view;
            dropTarget.setText(dropTarget.getText().toString() + dropped.getText().toString());
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
} 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use the local count variable to get the count of number times drag and drop happen.
2. You can get the id of drag and dropped view by using `v.getId();` in your switch case statements...

Comment: v.getid(); give view's id not button by which ChoiceDragListener() class is called

Comment: if you get the view id you can easily find out which button is dragged.Because View id is nothing but the button id which your pressed..

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map to keep track of how many times each item has been dragged

```
Map<Integer, Integer> dragMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

In your `onDrag()` method you can add new items to the dragMap or increment the count associated with existing ones

```
if (dragMap.get(dragTarget.getId() == null) {
    dragMap.put(dragTarget.getId(), 1);
}
else {
    dragMap.put(dragTarget.getId(), 
                dragMap.get(dragTarget.getId()++);
}
```

You'll need some additional code to check for the number of times an item has been dragged, and prevent the drag action if it exceeds a certain number.
This code would go in your `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:` block.

Comment: Ok, the above code is meant to give you a good pointer. You need to properly integrate it into your code.